# BIBR expend as per Input XML using LuaLaTeX

Tags: lua, luacode

In the XML file `cross-links` are not expended like **2–5** and final latex should be **\citep{B2,B3,B4,B5}**.

Any Number should expend in all the `cross-links` like, if XML coded as **11–18** it should be convert to **\citep{B11,B12,B13,B14,B15,B16,B17,B18}** (beginning to end). How to get the expected result using `LuaLaTeX`?

My XML is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change <?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
<para>The first <xref ref-type="section" rid="Sec1">Section 1</xref> description and correlation between gait impairment and hydrocephalus were made in 1965 by Hakim and Adam (<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B1">1</xref>). The etiology of idiopathic normal pressure hydrocephalus (iNPH) has not yet been entirely understood (<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B2">2</xref>&#x02013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B5">5</xref>). In elderly patients, other conditions such as spinal canal stenosis, Parkinson&#x00027;s disease, and polyneuropathy may influence the gait negatively.</para>
</art>]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local function process_instructions(el)
  for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
    local ntype = child:get_node_type()
    if ntype == "PI" and child._name=="LuaLaTeX" then
      local text = child._attr[ "_text" ]
      local newel = el:create_element("lualatex-instruction", {text = text})
      child:replace_node(newel)
    end
    if child:is_element() then
      process_instructions(child)
    end
  end
end

process_instructions(dom:root_node())

local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par")
-- handle the processing instruction
transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction",
    function(el)
        return el:get_attribute("text")
    end)
transform.print_tex(transformer:process_dom(dom))
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

I have expected output LaTeX file is:

```
Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in
engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change Sample XXX1 their mechanical properties. in a predictable
and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads,
Abc alleviate
vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required
or monitor their own condition.

The first Section 1 description and correlation between gait impairment and
hydrocephalus were made in 1965 by Hakim and Adam (**\citep{B1}**). The etiology of idio-
pathic normal pressure hydrocephalus (iNPH) has not yet been entirely under-
stood (**\citep{B2,B3,B4,B5}**). In elderly patients, other conditions such as spinal canal stenosis,
Parkinson’s disease, and polyneuropathy may influence the gait negatively.
```

Comment: you just assign a Lua string to `sample` and never use it, so this document has no output.

Comment: @David: Yes and does not know how to get the expect output using lualatex.

Comment: but there is no standard typeset form for xml. You would have to define how to handle each element and implement the transform to tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have updated the question. I know how to get the attribute value from `xref`. But not any idea expand the attribute values (like B2,B3,B4,B5).. How to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand it correctly, you don't have the numbers that you want to expand explicitly stated as attributes of the `xref` element, but rather encoded as two separate `xref` elements:

```
<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B2">2</xref>&#x02013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B5">5</xref>
```

I don't think it is a good idea, but we can try anyway. In this case, you will need some pre-processing of the DOM to detect these cases and convert them to something that can be used in the tranformer library. This code should do that:

```lua
-- try to find <xref> followed by dash and another <xref>
-- we then expand rid attributes
for _, xref in ipairs(dom:query_selector("xref[ref-type='bibr']")) do
  local first = xref:get_sibling_node(1)
  local second = xref:get_sibling_node(2)
  if first and second and
     first:is_text() and first:get_text() == "–" and -- next node must be "–" text
     second:is_element() and second:get_element_name() == "xref" -- second element must be <xref>
  then
    local rid1 = xref:get_attribute("rid") or ""
    local rid2 = second:get_attribute("rid") or ""
    local prefix1, number1 = rid1:match("(%a+)(%d+)")
    local prefix2, number2 = rid2:match("(%a+)(%d+)")
    -- expand only if prefixes match each other
    if prefix1 and prefix2 and prefix1 == prefix2 then
      -- expand numbers
      local t = {}
      for i = number1, number2 do
        t[#t+1] = prefix1 .. math.floor(i)
      end
      -- save expanded numbers
      xref:set_attribute("rid", table.concat(t, ","))
      -- remove unnecessary elements
      first:remove_node()
      second:remove_node()
    end
  end

end
```

It detects `<xref>` elements followed by dash and another `<xref>`, sets the expanded ids as the `rid` attribute, and removes the unnecessary dash and second `<xref>`. You can then declare this transform rule to convert `<xref>` with `ref-type` of `bibr` to `\citep`:

```
transformer:add_action("xref[ref-type='bibr']", "\\citep{@{rid}}")
```

The `@{rid}` action will print value of the `rid` attribute.

This is the translated TeX result:

```
\section{Scattering of flexural waves an electric current}
Smart testing structures are \$a+b\$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change  Sample XXX1 their mechanical properties. 
in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads,  \hspace*{12pt}Abc alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.\par
The first Section 1 description and correlation between gait impairment and hydrocephalus were made in 1965 by Hakim and Adam (\citep{B1}). 
The etiology of idiopathic normal pressure hydrocephalus (iNPH) has not yet been entirely understood (\citep{B2,B3,B4,B5}). 
In elderly patients, other conditions such as spinal canal stenosis, Parkinson's disease, and polyneuropathy may influence the gait negatively.\par
```

This is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change <?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
<para>The first <xref ref-type="section" rid="Sec1">Section 1</xref> description and correlation between gait impairment and hydrocephalus were made in 1965 by Hakim and Adam (<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B1">1</xref>). The etiology of idiopathic normal pressure hydrocephalus (iNPH) has not yet been entirely understood (<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B2">2</xref>&#x02013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B5">5</xref>). In elderly patients, other conditions such as spinal canal stenosis, Parkinson&#x00027;s disease, and polyneuropathy may influence the gait negatively.</para>
</art>]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local function process_instructions(el)
  for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
    local ntype = child:get_node_type()
    if ntype == "PI" and child._name=="LuaLaTeX" then
      local text = child._attr[ "_text" ]
      local newel = el:create_element("lualatex-instruction", {text = text})
      child:replace_node(newel)
    end
    if child:is_element() then
      process_instructions(child)
    end
  end
end

-- try to find <xref> followed by dash and another <xref>
-- we then expand rid attributes
for _, xref in ipairs(dom:query_selector("xref[ref-type='bibr']")) do
  local first = xref:get_sibling_node(1)
  local second = xref:get_sibling_node(2)
  if first and second and
     first:is_text() and first:get_text() == "–" and -- next node must be "–" text
     second:is_element() and second:get_element_name() == "xref" -- second element must be <xref>
  then
    local rid1 = xref:get_attribute("rid") or ""
    local rid2 = second:get_attribute("rid") or ""
    local prefix1, number1 = rid1:match("(%a+)(%d+)")
    local prefix2, number2 = rid2:match("(%a+)(%d+)")
    -- expand only if prefixes match each other
    if prefix1 and prefix2 and prefix1 == prefix2 then
      -- expand numbers
      local t = {}
      for i = number1, number2 do
        t[#t+1] = prefix1 .. math.floor(i)
      end
      -- save expanded numbers
      xref:set_attribute("rid", table.concat(t, ","))
      -- remove unnecessary elements
      first:remove_node()
      second:remove_node()
    end
  end

  
end

process_instructions(dom:root_node())

local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par")
transformer:add_action("xref[ref-type='bibr']", "\\citep{@{rid}}")
-- handle the processing instruction
transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction",
    function(el)
        return el:get_attribute("text")
    end)
local result = transformer:process_dom(dom)
print(result)
transform.print_tex(result)
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: It's possible to do lua script in separate LaTeX Style file?. It means like to add in the LaTeX file `\usepackage{bibr}` and all the lua scripts in `bibr.sty` file only, so no need any `luacode` in the LaTeX file.

Comment: @Balaji of course, you would just need to make a command that accepts XML code or filename and then processes it.

Comment: I have tried to cut the `luacode` from LaTeX and created `bibr.sty` file. But, it's showing compile error. Could you please advise how to do this. It's good to modify your answer...

Comment: @Balaji it would be best to post it as another question

Comment: I have posted new question <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692017/lua-script-in-separate-latex-style-file>