# Lua script in separate LaTeX Style File

Tags: cross-referencing, luatex, luacode

I have successfully loaded `XML` in LuaLaTeX with help of `Michal.h21`. Now I would like to store all the customized defined `Lua Script` in a separate LaTeX Style file, like `bibr.sty`, so that I will call just `\usepackage{bibr}` in the LaTeX file.

In the `bibr.sty` file all the customized defined `lua script` need to be defined.

My BIBR Cross-Links XML file is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>The first <xref ref-type="section" rid="Sec1">Section 1</xref> description and correlation between gait impairment and hydrocephalus were made in 1965 by Hakim and Adam (<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B1">1</xref>). The etiology of idiopathic normal pressure hydrocephalus (iNPH) has not yet been entirely understood (<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B2">2</xref>&#x02013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B5">5</xref>). In elderly patients, other conditions such as spinal canal stenosis, Parkinson&#x00027;s disease, and polyneuropathy may influence the gait negatively.</para>
</art>]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local function process_instructions(el)

-- try to find <xref> followed by dash and another <xref>
-- we then expand rid attributes
for _, xref in ipairs(dom:query_selector("xref[ref-type='bibr']")) do
  local first = xref:get_sibling_node(1)
  local second = xref:get_sibling_node(2)
  if first and second and
     first:is_text() and first:get_text() == "–" and -- next node must be "–" text
     second:is_element() and second:get_element_name() == "xref" -- second element must be <xref>
  then
    local rid1 = xref:get_attribute("rid") or ""
    local rid2 = second:get_attribute("rid") or ""
    local prefix1, number1 = rid1:match("(%a+)(%d+)")
    local prefix2, number2 = rid2:match("(%a+)(%d+)")
    -- expand only if prefixes match each other
    if prefix1 and prefix2 and prefix1 == prefix2 then
      -- expand numbers
      local t = {}
      for i = number1, number2 do
        t[#t+1] = prefix1 .. math.floor(i)
      end
      -- save expanded numbers
      xref:set_attribute("rid", table.concat(t, ","))
      -- remove unnecessary elements
      first:remove_node()
      second:remove_node()
    end
  end

  
end
end

process_instructions(dom:root_node())

local transformer = transform.new()
transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par")
transformer:add_action("xref[ref-type='bibr']", "\\citep{@{rid}}")
-- handle the processing instruction
transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction",
    function(el)
        return el:get_attribute("text")
    end)
local result = transformer:process_dom(dom)
-- Print Output Result in Command-Prompt/Terminal
print(result)
-- Print Output Result in PDF uncomment below
--transform.print_tex(result)
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: why do you want a latex style here rather than just include the lua?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have need to include many developments through `lua script`. So, Its better to include all the `lua code` in `Main LaTeX` file, to maintain each and separate `LaTeX Style file` (for fixing any bugs our ends in future).

Comment: even if you offer a .sty to the user to save them doing `\directlua{require("Balaji")}` I would put the lua in a .lua file and include it that way in the latex package, using lua inline in the tex especially via luacode is tricky and inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David suggested, it is a good idea to move the Lua code to a standalone file, to prevent some interaction issues between TeX and Lua. It could look like this, `bibr.lua`:

```lua
local M = {}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"

local function process_instructions(el)
  for _, child in ipairs(el:get_children()) do
    local ntype = child:get_node_type()
    if ntype == "PI" and child._name=="LuaLaTeX" then
      local text = child._attr[ "_text" ]
      local newel = el:create_element("lualatex-instruction", {text = text})
      child:replace_node(newel)
    end
    if child:is_element() then
      process_instructions(child)
    end
  end
end

function M.process(sample)
  local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
  -- try to find <xref> followed by dash and another <xref>
  -- we then expand rid attributes
  for _, xref in ipairs(dom:query_selector("xref[ref-type='bibr']")) do
    local first = xref:get_sibling_node(1)
    local second = xref:get_sibling_node(2)
    if first and second and
      first:is_text() and first:get_text() == "–" and -- next node must be "–" text
      second:is_element() and second:get_element_name() == "xref" -- second element must be <xref>
    then
      local rid1 = xref:get_attribute("rid") or ""
      local rid2 = second:get_attribute("rid") or ""
      local prefix1, number1 = rid1:match("(%a+)(%d+)")
      local prefix2, number2 = rid2:match("(%a+)(%d+)")
      -- expand only if prefixes match each other
      if prefix1 and prefix2 and prefix1 == prefix2 then
        -- expand numbers
        local t = {}
        for i = number1, number2 do
          t[#t+1] = prefix1 .. math.floor(i)
        end
        -- save expanded numbers
        xref:set_attribute("rid", table.concat(t, ","))
        -- remove unnecessary elements
        first:remove_node()
        second:remove_node()
      end
    end


  end

  process_instructions(dom:root_node())

  local transformer = transform.new()
  transformer:add_action("title", "\\section{@<.>}")
  transformer:add_action("para", "@<.>\\par")
  transformer:add_action("xref[ref-type='bibr']", "\\citep{@{rid}}")
  -- handle the processing instruction
  transformer:add_custom_action("lualatex-instruction",
  function(el)
    return el:get_attribute("text")
  end)
  local result = transformer:process_dom(dom)
  print(result)
  transform.print_tex(result)
end

function M.process_file(filename)
  local f = io.open(filename, "r")
  if not f then return nil, "Cannot open file: " .. filename end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  M.process(content)
end

return M
```

I've moved the code that was originally in the main body of the `luacode` environment to a function `M.process`. The `M` table is returned from this library, so it will enable you to use this code in this way:

```
 local bibr = require "bibr"
 bibr.process("xml code...")
```

I've also made another function, `M.process_file`, which will transform XML file, so you don't need to pass the XML code to your document.

You then need a LaTeX package that will provide commands that can be used in your documents. It can look like this, `bibr.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{bibr}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{processbibr}{+b}{%
  \directlua{
    local bibr = require "bibr"
    bibr.process([[\unexpanded{#1}]])
  }
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand\processbibrfile{m}{%
  \directlua{%
    local bibr = require "bibr"
    bibr.process_file("#1")
  }
}

\endinput
```

It provides `processbibr` environment and `\processbibrfile` command. The environment can be used if you want to put the XML code in the document, the command for including external XML files.

It can be used like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibr}
\begin{document}
\begin{processbibr}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are $a+b$ components Reduce acoustic noise used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment change <?LuaLaTeX Sample XXX1?> their mechanical properties. in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <?LuaLaTeX \hspace*{12pt}Abc?> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
<para>The first <xref ref-type="section" rid="Sec1">Section 1</xref> description and correlation between gait impairment and hydrocephalus were made in 1965 by Hakim and Adam (<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B1">1</xref>). The etiology of idiopathic normal pressure hydrocephalus (iNPH) has not yet been entirely understood (<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B2">2</xref>&#x02013;<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="B5">5</xref>). In elderly patients, other conditions such as spinal canal stenosis, Parkinson&#x00027;s disease, and polyneuropathy may influence the gait negatively.</para>
</art>
\end{processbibr}

\processbibrfile{test.xml}
\end{document}
```

In general, I think it is better to use `\processbibrfile`, as you shouldn't run into strange errors that can happen when you include the XML file directly to your TeX file.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You put this

```
\ProvidesPackage{bibr}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
% HERE YOUR CODE, exactly as it is in your example
\end{luacode*}
```

in a file, and save it with `.sty` extension in the same folder as your `.tex`.

Comment: @lacobus1983: It's working fine. But Input may different each `XML`. In this file it's `sample`. How to get XML Filename from user when running `lualatex`?

Comment: @Balaji I'm not a lua expert... Perhaps you should use a method to read the file, have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97822/how-to-read-a-file-with-luatex